# Unable to target specific CSS class for jQuery fadeToggle()

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am building a test site to play with jQuery:

```
<div class="frame25" >
    <div class="frame50 stadt">
        Paris</br>
        <img src="paris-cut.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="frame50">
        <div class="tickets">
            Tickets</br>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Now I've got multiple of these cities as div boxes and only want only the matching ticket div to show, when I click on the image of ONE city. (I could resolve this with multiple IDs, but that is not the elegant way for which I seek)

jQuery looks like this:

```
$("document").ready(function(){
    $(".tickets").hide();
    $(".stadt").click(function(event) {
        if($(this).parents.(".tickets")){
           event.fadeToggle();
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: You may start by removing the quotes around document.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/p8rws1dj/1/

Comment: You should also wrap that text in a proper text tag **and** stop using break tags for spacing.

Comment: And you have a dot too much after parents

Comment: Thanks guys, also for fixing my bad coding ;) - it's working now!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Working code (http://jsfiddle.net/z2meacz6/)

```
$(function(){
    $(".tickets").hide();
    $(".stadt").click(function(event) {
        $(this).parent().find(".tickets").fadeToggle();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    $(".tickets").hide();
    $(".stadt").click(function (event) {debugger;
        var statTickets=$(this).siblings('.frame50').find('.tickets');
        statTickets.show();
        $('.tickets').not(statTickets).hide();
    });
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/7qydawqk/)** here (included code to hide other tickets)

Comment: Thanks! This also removes the other ticket divs, not intended, but very good to know.

Comment: Yup, if you dont want to remove other tickets, you can comment our last line. Do remember to accept it, if it solved your purpose. Thanks